# sqlite limitation on iphone abour storage

Tags: iphone, sqlite

how much data i can store in sqlite in iphone?

Answer (score 1):

As Steve said;  limited by available disk space.

However, there is an additional limitation;  you really don't want to be storing BLOBs (big blobs of binary data) in a SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

It's limited by how much available disk space you have on the phone.